# Optimally positioning pie chart data labels in Excel with VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, charts

I have a worksheet where I create a pie chart from data from a database. The chart changes based on the data it is displaying so the slices often change size.

I want to display the data labels outside the slices with leader lines if the slice is small enough to warrant it.

I have got most of the way there but the trouble is the labels often get messed up and end up overlapping one another or appearing too far away from their slice. This results in me manually having to reposition the labels when I update the chart.

Here is an example of the chart after changing the data. We can see "property" and "redemption" overlap whilst "macro" and "gold" have ended up too far away resulting in superfluous leader lines appearing.

[image]

Is there some VBA script that is good at repositioning the labels without these problems? The built-in excel positioning is insufficient as it tries to put some labels inside the slices if they're big enough, which would result in illegible labels due to the color scheme.

Comment: Use the built-in Best Fit option for label positioning. Then select each label that is located inside a wedge (one click selects all labels, the next selects just one), and use the Outside End option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short answer to your question, you can manipulate labels through VBA, but I think you'll have a difficult time creating an efficient algorithm to cleanly place labels on a continually changing pie chart.

I'll suggest an alternative to the pie chart (they're really not a great charting alternative, here's a place to start looking if you're curious [Save Pies for Dessert](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/08-21-07.pdf)).  A bar chart is an alternative both for how it displays data and how it handles the labeling issue that is causing you problems.  Here's a sample with the data you provided in your example:

[image: Pie Alternative]

Here there's no worry about label placement or location, the investment name is always adjacent to the corresponding bar without the need for leaders.  The percentage is labeled clearly inside the corresponding bar, with the relative lengths giving a visual clue as to their relative sizes.  Sorting can be done to accentuate values (as in the example) or could be changed to a static (e.g. alphabetical) so that easy comparisons can be made between different versions of the same chart.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that a bar chart is clearer and easier to manage. My issue is we need to conform to the what guidelines that are set for us, although I will certainly bring up the point. And you are also right about the difficulty of positioning the labels; I was hoping someone else had potentially come across a similar problem and developed a solution for it.